# Multiply multiple columns by multiple columns inplace

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a dataframe that look like this:

```
              ivol  Front Face  Back Face  Left Face  Right Face  Front jvol  Back jvol  Left jvol  Right jvol  
    row col                                                                                                    
    99  49   5792          1           1          1          0        5734        5850       5791       5793   
        50   5793          1           1          0          0        5735        5851       5792       5794   
        51   5794          1           1          0          0        5736        5852       5793       5795   
        52   5795          1           1          0          0        5737        5853       5794       5796
```

I need to multiply certain columns (`xxx Face` columns by `xxx jvol` columns) and rewrite the results inplace (`xxx jvol` column). The results should be like this:

```
         ivol  Front Face  Back Face  Left Face  Right Face  Front jvol  Back jvol  Left jvol  Right jvol  
row col                                                                                                    
99  49   5792          1           1          1          0        5734        5850       5791        0
    50   5793          1           1          0          0        5735        5851        0          0   
    51   5794          1           1          0          0        5736        5852        0          0   
    52   5795          1           1          0          0        5737        5853        0          0
```

I can do it by:

```
df['Front jvol'] = df['Front Face'] * df['Front jvol']
df['Back jvol'] = df['Back Face'] * df['Back jvol']
df['Left jvol'] = df['Left Face'] * df['Left jvol']
df['Right jvol'] = df['Right Face'] * df['Right jvol']
```

But, it gives `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` warning and I don't conformable to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension, since your columns have common prefixes:

```
columns = ["Front", "Back", "Left", "Right"]

mapping = {f"{col} jvol":  df[f"{col} Face"] * df[f"{col} jvol"] 
            for col in columns}
```

Final result:

```
df.assign(**mapping)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out with `dataframe.assign`

```
df.assign(
    front_jvol=df['Front Face'] * df['Front jvol'],
    back_jvol=df['Back Face'] * df['Back jvol'],
    left_jvol=df['Left Face'] * df['Left jvol'],
    right_jvol=df['Right Face'] * df['Right jvol']
)
```

Comment: This solution creates new columns (fron_jvol etc.). How can I store them in the existing columns (Front jvol etc.)?

Comment: it returns a new dataframe object with all original columns in addition to new ones, just reassign them to your existing `df`

Comment: Insightful suggestion.